# Removing a failed Microsoft Store installation

Tags: uwp

When I try to deploy and debug my UWP application from Visual Studio 2017 I get the error:

> DEP0900: Failed to unregister application "Microsoft.ProjectTorino_1.1.1.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe". [0x80073CFA] Deployment Remove operation with target volume C: on Package Microsoft.ProjectTorino_1.1.1.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe from:   failed with error 0x80070490.

I think this is because there is an existing deployment of the same app on my PC from the Microsoft Store. But that deployment failed and so there's nothing I can uninstall.

How do I get rid of a failed installation from the store so that I can deploy from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this: Open Powershell, then type the following command

```
>Remove-AppXPackage
```

Then supply the package name

```
Package: Microsoft.ProjectTorino_1.1.1.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Comment: This doesn't work in this case, but I am sure it is supposed to! The cmd 'wsreset' was another possibility

Comment: Thanks! Please help to enhance my answer, I cannot verify if wsreset can fix this issue.